# How to convert string tuples inside a list of a list to a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Suppose we have a list with this structure:

```
chunks=[[('Spain', 'A1'), ('Spain', 'A2'), ('Spain', 'A3'), ('Spain', 'A4')]]
```

I am trying to change it to this structure:

```
[['Spain', 'A1'], ['Spain', 'A2'], ['Spain', 'A3'], ['Spain', 'A4']]
```

I've tried `[list(x) for x in chunks]` but nothing changes.

How could I accomplish this task?

Comment: the above code should work but you are missing a layer, you can nest it in a for loop iterating over the list

Comment: Your code should work fine for a list of tuples. Why is the list inside another list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map`

**Ex:**

```
chunks=[[('Spain', 'A1'), ('Spain', 'A2'), ('Spain', 'A3'), ('Spain', 'A4')]]
print(list(map(list, *chunks)))
# --> [['Spain', 'A1'], ['Spain', 'A2'], ['Spain', 'A3'], ['Spain', 'A4']]
```

or using an extra loop

```
# OR
print([list(j) for i in chunks for j in i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go one level deeper.

Assuming `len(chunks)` will always be 1, you can use indexing:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in chunks[0]]
[['Spain', 'A1'], ['Spain', 'A2'], ['Spain', 'A3'], ['Spain', 'A4']]
```

If `len(chunks)` may not be 1, you'll need to consider what the output should be. For example, you might want to flatten:

```
chunks=[
    [('Spain', 'A1'), ('Spain', 'A2'), ('Spain', 'A3'), ('Spain', 'A4')],
    [('Portugal', 'B1')]]
```

```
>>> [list(x) for y in chunks for x in y]
[['Spain', 'A1'],
 ['Spain', 'A2'],
 ['Spain', 'A3'],
 ['Spain', 'A4'],
 ['Portugal', 'B1']]
```